# Rename files in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, rename

I am writing a script to rename my files, The current syntax for filename is `program 1.c` and I want to change this to `cprogram-program1.c`.

I am unable to get this format. Few conditions for simplicity are:

- assume that there are only 10 files i.e: 0,1,2,3..9

My procedure to achieve this:

- First we need to filter the files to find out files that follow the given pattern
- Then we need to filter the filename into substrings ignorer to verify whether they are in a proper format
- If they are in a proper format, then we can edit the filename in the way we need it.

I am stuck on step 1 and 2, this is sort of what I am doing:

```
for fn in *; do --> this loops over the files 
 program=${fn:0:7}
 number=${..} --> number between 0 and 9
 extension=${..} --> gets file extension like .c

if [ "$program" == "program"  ]
 then
    if [ "$number" -ge 0 ] && [ "$number" -le 9 ]
     then

         if [ "$extension" == ".c" ]
          then
            --> edit code 
          fi

     fi
fi
done
```

My problem: I have tried many permutations of the above example, but I am unable to get what I want. Any help, simple method of doing this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do the current filenames really have a space; eg, `program 1.c`?

Comment: @jasonwryan yeah there is a space

Comment: `for file in *.c; do [[( -f $file && $file =~ program )]] && echo  cprogram-"${file/ /}"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
for fn in *
do  case $fn in
    (program*[1-8].c)
        : do something;;
    (other*program*[09].ext)
        : do something with this match;;
    (this*match|*or*|*any*"$of"*these*matches)
        : do something with these matches
        : do as many lines as you want;;
    (*) : catch all last default match
    esac
done
```

A commonly used technique in `case` statements is to prune unwanted matches with more specific patterns than your generally desired pattern. For example:

```
for fn in *
do  case $fn in
    (*[0-9][0-9].c) ;;
    (program*[1-8].c)
        echo mv "$fn" "${fn%???}0${fn#"${fn%???}"}"
    esac
done
```

In the above example the first `*[0-9][0-9].c` pattern matches all `$fn` values where two or more digits might occur to the left of the extension. The execution block for those matches is empty - null - nothing at all happens when a match is found. Most importantly, though, because `case` statements work top-down, what this means is the only results ever matched for the action block will contain only the one digit to the left of the extension, and the example `echo` command would insert a `0` before each and every one of those occurring between 1 and 8.

Comment: thanks for the approach, I am having trouble executing the case statement, this example doesn't return anything : for fn in *
do  case $fn in
    (*) : echo "hi" ;;
   esac
done

Comment: ^ can you please tell me what the issue might be

Comment: @Mathew - yeah, of course. The issue is the `:` null command. I prefixed all of the command statements with `:` true on purpose - so nothing would happen. It's all a do nothing there, but if you remove your `:` colon, your command will print `hi`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, dispense with the script and use a `rename` tool instead.

Frustratingly there are (at least) two different instances of `rename` depending on your distribution. On some systems the Perl version may be called `prename`. However, you can tell which one you have by running `rename -n ';' /dev/null`. If nothing happens you have the Perl version. If you get an error it's the other one.

> The current syntax for filename is `program 1.c` and I want to change this to `cprogram-program1.c`. Assume that there are only 9 files i.e: 0,1,2,3..9

1. The Perl-based `rename` (`prename`)

   ```
   rename 's/^/cprogram-/; s/\s//' program\ ?.c
   ```
2. The other `rename`

   ```
   rename -v 'program ' cprogram-program program\ ?.c
   ```